# How to append user input time data (minutes and seconds) into an array using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form where the user can input time (minutes and seconds) it took for them to complete a certain task and I want to push this input into an empty array.

Currently, when I try to print the array to the console, it says that there is one value within the array, however does not display the value.

```
<form id="mile1">
    Mile 1 Time: <input mile1="mile1" type="time" size="20">
</form>
<br>
<button class="test" onclick="storeValue()">test</button>
```

```
var userTimes = [];

let storeValue = function() {
    let inputTime = document.getElementById('mile1').value;
    userTimes.push(userTimes);
}
```

I want to be able to know that the value input in the form has been stored in the array and can be later used for further calculations. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `mile1 = 'mile1'` should be `id = 'mile1'`

Comment: push inputTime not userTimes. It should be `userTimes.push(inputTime);`

Comment: If the entire task will be completed within the same session, it may provide a better user experience to include logic that automatically marks the time when they begin their task. Then within a trigger of completion (e.g. save button), you calculate the elapsed time in your codebase. That way, there are no additional steps for the end user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution that includes validation:

```
<form id="mile-form">
    Mile 1 Time: <input id = "mile1" type= "time" size="20">
</form>

<button class="test" onclick="storeValue()">test</button>
```

```
const userTimes = [];

const storeValue = function () {
  const mile1 = document.querySelector("#mile1");

  if (!mile1.value || mile1.validationMessage) {
    console.log("Error message here");
  } else {
    userTimes.push(mile1.value);
  }

}
```

Note that it's a code smell to have global variables. You should consider refactoring to tighten the scope of `userTimes`.

Answer (score 0):

Take the value of the input element not the form. And you need to push `inputTime` into the array.

```js
userTimes = [];

let storeValue = function () {

    let inputTime = document.getElementById('mile1').value;

    userTimes.push(inputTime);
    console.log(userTimes);

}
```

```html
<form >
    Mile 1 Time: <input id="mile1" type= 'time' size='20'> </form> <br>

<button class='test' onclick="storeValue()">test</button>
```

Comment: It is saving blank entries.

Comment: @AlokMali You must set the hour, minute, and period for the value to be an actual time.

Answer (score 0):

I created a snippet for reference that is currently working. There were two things that needed updating in order for this to work.

1. The id `mile1` needed to be on the input, not the form.
2. The `.push` should be pushing the value, not the array.

Hopefully this helps!

```js
userTimes = [];

let storeValue = function () {

    let inputTime = document.getElementById('mile1').value;

    userTimes.push(inputTime);
    console.log(userTimes);
}
```

```html
<form>
    Mile 1 Time: <input id="mile1" mile1 = 'mile1' type= 'time' size='20'> </form> <br>

<button class='test' onclick="storeValue()">test</button>
```